# perform fuzzy matching on a large set of dictionary keys

Tags: performance, python-3.x

Any suggestions on improving the speed of below code. My dictionary is rather large in fold of * 100000 and expected to grow larger every day.

I am open to completely new ideas or approaches to do the below operation.

```
from pyxdameraulevenshtein import damerau_levenshtein_distance, normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance
name = 'john doe'

word_dict = { 
              'john' : ['ID1','ID2', 'AB2' ,'AS1']
             ,'doe' : ['ID1','ID4', 'AB2' ,'AS6']
             ,'jahn' : ['ID3','ID2', 'AB2' ,'AS5']
             }
# perform iteration on dictionary keys . compute and filter if damerau edit distance is less than 2 
all_matches = []
for nWord in set(name.split()):
    match = []
    match += [(word,list(word_dict[word]), int((1-normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance(nWord,word))* 100))\
    for word in word_dict if damerau_levenshtein_distance(nWord,word) in [0,1,2]]
    all_matches.append(match)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [BKTrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree). [Here](http://nullwords.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/the-bk-tree-a-data-structure-for-spell-checking/) is a less technical description. There is a Python library on PyPI: [pybktree](https://pypi.org/project/pybktree/).

You create the BKTree once (once a day?) from the keys in the dictionary. Then run all the queries against the BKTree.

It would look something like this untested code:

```
import pybktree
from pyxdameraulevenshtein import damerau_levenshtein_distance

tree = pybktree.BKTree(damerau_levenshtein_distance, word_dict.keys())

all_matches = []

for target in set(name.split()):
    all_matches.extend(tree.find(target, MAX_DISTANCE))]
```

`all_matches` would be a list of (distance, word) tuples.

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me a lot . Any suggestions on how to store the tree structure ?

Comment: @abhilashDasari, you can use the `pickle` module from the standard library to save it to orload it from a file.